# Autocomplete object property in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, autocomplete

Maybe it will be a very lame question, but i just try.
I built my own MVC framework.

In the controller, i am creating a new object, called $Object.
Object class has a private property $id, and a getter getId();

In the controller, i am creating a new View(), what is loading a template file.
So my controllers seems like this:

```
$View = new View('templateFile.php');
$View->Object = new Object();
$View->show();
```

If i am editing this in the controller, when typing $View->Object->ge... netbeans automatically try to autocomplete it to getId or offers all methods what starts with "ge".
Cool.

I am editing the template file, where the $this is the View object.
When i type, $this-> and CTLR+Space, there are no suggession.

Is it possible to earn this somehow?

That could be a dream, if i could do this with $this->Object-> and CTRL+Space.

Here are my important pieces of my View class:

```
public function show() {
        echo $this->getViewContent();
}

public function getViewContent() {
    $container = null;
    $defaultViewHeader = '';
    if ($this->showDefaultViewHeader) {
        if (file_exists($this->viewsDir . $this->defaultViewHeaderFile)) {
            $defaultViewHeader = $this->getContent($this->viewsDir . $this->defaultViewHeaderFile);
        } else {
            $defaultViewHeader = $this->getContent($this->commonDir . $this->defaultViewHeaderFile);
        }
    }
    $pageContent = $this->getContent($this->file);
    if ($this->showDefaultViewHeader) {
        $pageContent = $defaultViewHeader . $pageContent;
    }
    if ($this->showContainer) {
        $container = $this->getContent($this->viewsDir . $this->containerFile);
        $pageContent = str_replace('[' . HTD_PAGECONTENT . ']', $pageContent, $container);
    }
    return $pageContent;
}

public function getContent($file) {
    ob_start();
    include ($file);
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could specify a variable type to netbeans using the "var" annotation. 
Try to add this line into your template :

```
/* @var $this View */
```

More on this here https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/defining_a_variable_type_in

Comment: with, or without it i can access the View properties and methods, but not the attached objects.

Comment: Ok, i will try this. Now i noticed, if do this: /* @var $RedLegion Legion */ and then $RedLegion = $this->RedLegion; after that, i can access the autocomplete feature. I will check deeper that document what you linked. Thank you.